# pymssql executes stored procedure but returns no results

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pymssql

I am trying to execute a stored procedure on a SQL server and save the results using python -- I decided to use pymssql because it seemed like the simplest solution.

```
print pymssql.__version__

server = 'MY\SERVER'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
database = 'db'
proc = 'checkin'

with pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:

        cursor.callproc(proc, (eha, ip, url, alias, location, rotation))
        conn.commit()

        f = open('/var/wwwdata/locations.txt', 'w')
        for row in cursor:
            print(row['Alias'])
            f.write(row['Alias'] + '\n')
        f.close()
```

The SQL Query performs some insert/update and ends with

```
SELECT Alias FROM MyTable
```

Running the SP from SSMS works correctly, however running the SP from Python performs the insert/update functionality however returns no results.

According to [pymssql documentation](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/faq.html), this is a known problem. However, I cannot find a solution that works.

I tried a few different suggestions I found around the web, including

- Checked my pymssql version (2.1.1)
- Declare cursor with `dict=true`
- Use `cursor.nextset()` after `cursor.commit()`
- Fetch results using `cursor.fetchall()` or `cursor.fetchone()`, both of which result in similar exceptions:

> OperationalError: Statement not executed or executed statement has no resultset

Does anyone know a fix for this particular problem? Or perhaps is there a more stable solution for python interfacing with SQL server (especially for calling stored procedures)? I guess I should also ask, am I going about this entirely wrong?

Also thought it might be worth noting: OS is Raspbian running on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Answer (score 9):

I have managed to work out the problem. Calling `conn.commit()` was making the cursor lose its results. I probably misread some of the pymssql documentation and added that line by mistake - code works perfect without it.

**EDIT**: I noticed after I made this change, the stored procedure would return the results however the insert/update parts of the procedure were not saving. Now it's clear to me what `conn.commit()` was doing. If your stored procedure returns results AND makes changes to the database, you need to call `conn.commit()` after you fetch them.

```
server = 'MY\SERVER'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
database = 'db'
proc = 'checkin'

with pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc(proc, (eha, ip, url, alias, location, rotation))
        cursor.nextset()
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        f = open('/var/wwwdata/locations.txt', 'w')
        for result in results:
            print result[0]
            f.write(result[0])
        f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. I would never find this out on my own.

Comment: Thanks for posting this - it cleared up an issue that I had as well. By adding conn.commit, I was able to get my stored procedure to work. I just spent three hours puzzling over this. I'm fairly amazed that there are not more questions about python interactivity with MS SQL.