# Turbodbc - Getting Output from Multi-Statement Query

Tags: python, sql, turbodbc

I am struggling to access the results of a stored procedure giving me the identity of the row just inserted using Turbodbc 4.1.2, Python 3.7, and SQL Server 2017.

My procedure runs along the following lines:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testSP] @var INT
AS

INSERT INTO testTable VALUES (@var)
SELECT 4 --intermediate step to prove concept
--SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as [scope_id] --final goal
--SELECT @@IDENTITY AS '[scope_id]'
```

My Turbodbc code looks like this:

```
cnxn = connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', server=srv, database=db, uid=user, pwd=password, turbodbc_options=options)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

cmd = "EXEC testSP 1"
crsr.execute(cmd)
df = pd.DataFrame(crsr.fetchallnumpy())
```

When running the stored procedure without any inserts (ie, just "SELECT 4"), the result set returns fine. However, when running with the insert, which operates correctly, I receive an error "turbodbc.exceptions.InterfaceError: No active result set". The query runs fine in SSMS.

I am guessing that this is because I am receiving two result sets back - one for the insert, and one for the select. I saw from a couple questions on SO that nextset function is available in [pymssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469291/pymssql-executes-stored-procedure-but-returns-no-results) and [pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263781/pyodbc-return-multiple-cursors-from-stored-procedure-with-db2), but that the same functionality is not available in [turbodbc](https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc/issues/145).

How can I access the second part in my multi-statement query using turbodbc? This seems like a relatively simple issue, but I have been banging my head against the wall for a few hours.

Comment: For future people coming across: this is a fundamental limitation of turbodbc - please see the Github issue that I opened: https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc/issues/323